# Can i get automaticcaly the namespaces of an XML file?

Tags: python, xml

I dont know if its even possible , but imagine i have several XML files with differents namespaces, and i want to loop through them and parse them is there any way to get the namespace and put it in a variable so its scallable ? or i have to change for each files manually the namespace ?

like there is a sample of XML file :

```
<Document xmlns:xsi = "sample" xmlns ="SampleNamespace">
```

is there any way to get "SampleNameSpace" in a variable ?

Like for each file that i will parse, i can recuperate the file's specified namespace

Thank you for your help

Comment: You've asked several different questions here. Getting all the namespaces declared in a document is one thing; getting the namespace of the root element is another. Note that a "file" does not have a namespace, unless you mean the namespace of the root element of the XML document contained in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can get both namespaces in your sample into a list which can you later access:

```
samp = """
<Document xmlns:xsi = "sample" xmlns ="SampleNamespace">
something
</Document>
"""
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.XML(samp)
spaces = []
for i in doc.xpath('//*'):
    for v in i.nsmap.values():
       spaces.append(v)
spaces
```

Output:

```
['sample', 'SampleNamespace']
```